# Display post only for login user - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, function

I have use below Code

```
    if (!post_password_required($post) ) {
     // we will show password form here
      echo get_the_password_form(); ?>

    <?php }else{
    // Here My content
     ?>
```

But i want to use user login password not check with post private password

Comment: So instead of `echo get_the_password_form();`, why don't you redirect them to the login form?

Comment: do you want to do the protected password for entire website??@Gaurang

Comment: No particular one section i have tab navigation and there i need to one tab content should be password protected which password should be user password so user easy remember password @priyanka

Comment: I had given the answer with my comment @GaurangSuthar

Comment: I have one web application and this functionality use in customer dashboard so user is already login so how can i redirect into login page @Michael

Comment: So you want to have password protected posts, but the password should be the login password? What about `is_user_logged_in()`?

Comment: yes@Michael is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try it updated code,

```html
<?php /* Template Name: pw-protect */ ?>

<?php
    global $post;
    get_header();

    if ( ! post_password_required( $post ) ) {
          // Your custom code should here
        include('indiPartnership.php');


    }else{
        // we will show password form here
        echo get_the_password_form();
    }

?>
```

You get the solution on same!

Comment: ok but which password use in that case i have already use this code but I need use to login password not post password.